# Rails + Spree: Cant checkout in test env "Unable to Authorize Credit Card: Bogus Gateway: Forced failure"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Hi I currently have a spree app and I'm trying to test out checkout in my preview environment, however it's not working. I have only have one payment method:

```
Credit Card     Gateway::Bogus  Preview     Both    Yes
```

but when I try to check out it says

> Unable to Authorize Credit Card: Bogus Gateway: Forced failure.

However, in my staging environment, the checkout works with the same payment method configuration. Isn't the Bogus gateway supposed to just work since it's just for testing purposes? I'm really not familiar with spree (this is a legacy app), so any help to get me past the checkout is much appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 10):

The source behind this will perhaps yield some insight:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.1.2/core/app/models/spree/gateway/bogus.rb#L37-L41

The bogus gateway will only accept credit card numbers in the list at the top of the class.  Are you using one of those numbers?

Comment: Thanks gmac! I tried with one of those and it gave me the same error... I'm actually using like one of the earliest versions of Spree (v. 0.11.0). Do you know if there's a similar list but for that version?

Comment: Actually I found it. But I'm still running into the same issue even when I paste the CC numbers in... I have no clue why

Comment: The v0.11.0 code is located here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v0.11.0/vendor/extensions/payment_gateway/app/models/gateway/bogus.rb#L36  You can throw some logging information in there in order to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

To pass the checkout steps in other to place a successful test order follow the following steps.

**Name on card**

Enter `Bogus Gateway`

**Credit card number**

Enter each of these in turn to simulate different types of transaction:

1. Enter `1` to simulate a successful transaction
2. Enter `2` to simulate a failed transaction
3. Enter `3` to simulate an Exception (this generates
   a message indicating that an error has occurred with the provider.)

**CVV**

Enter any 3-digit number (for example, 111.)

**Expiry Date**

Enter any date in the future.

Source [Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/checkout-settings/test-orders)